# Did a command in Command Prompt, should I change them?

Tags: wireless-networking, netsh

I was following a tutorial online for creating a WiFi hotspot and it said to do this line in command prompt (as administrator):

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=www.FastTechBuzz.com key=FastTechBuzz
```

What did I actually do and should I restore or delete something now? I think I didn't create a hotspot. I didn't even do the next steps from the tutorial. Should the hostednetwork option be set to allow?

Comment: **Never** execute commands if you don't have at least a vague idea of what you are doing. Especially on a command line, if you are not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

what you did was to ask your wireless card or system setup to behave like a router.By typing following;

**netsh**   called the netsh command

**wlan**    you indicated which hardware you wanted to start working with

**set**     Basically a command to netsh to do something

**hostednetwork**    What you asked netsh to concentrate on

**mode=allow**    You asked for the hostednetwork to be allowed for communication -basically

**ssid=**    Whatever you put after the = sign is the ID or name you gave the hostednetwork

**key=**     That is the password to the hostednetwork

If you added **keyUsage=**   then you are defining how the key should be used (usually ***persistent*** follows the = sign)

Now after doing this you can either turn it on or leave it there. If you turn it on, you can leave it to run so you connect with your other devices (after you share your internet connection through it) or turn it off if you want to.

To turn it on, just type   **netsh wlan start hostednetwork**

I guess you get the whole gig by now...you are simply asking for it to be **started**.

To turn is off, well your guess is as good as mine...,   **netsh wlan stop hostednetwork**

Revert if you still have any issues. Dont worry, if you dont turn it on, it will have no effect on your system anyway. An at least the password sort of protects and regulates who gets access to it...thus if you give them access.

Answer (score 0):

You just updated your wifi on your computer to act as a hotspot. You gave it an ID and password and allowed others to connect to it from their wireless devices (in the same way you normally connect direct to a router).

Answer (score 0):

The hosted network is controlled with

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

and

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
```

I’m sure this is also written in your guide. ;)

So basically your changes didn’t affect anything set. You can just forget about them, if you like.

Comment: @Dave Rook said that I just made my WiFi to act as a hotspot, so aren't I supposed to stop the hotspot? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: No, you just set it up. Without flipping the switch, so to say.

Answer (score 0):

**netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=name key=password**

This command asks your wireless card to behave as router as well as to  allow card to host the network.

There is no problem unless or otherwise u start the hosted network with this command

**netsh wlan start hostednetwork**

You can also stop by

**netsh wlan stop hostednetwork**

This command creates creates reliable adhoc network cos it creates password of WPA-2 encryption. You can see this by

**netsh wlan show hostednetwork**

Dont forget to share your ethernet connection in properties and assign it to your hosted network.